# How does google search finds important links on a website

Tags: search, web-applications, seo, search-engine

I wanted to know that sometimes when I search for something on google it shows some results(website links), but it also shows some important links on that website.

I wanted to know that is it a feature of the website or Google uses something to find those main links of the website? Is it related to search engine optimization?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how Google crawls a page, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean [Google’s sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334).

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

(See [this [closed] question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17519796/1591669).)

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with click-through rates of those links. For example, Googling 'Amazon' brings up amazon.com, with a handful of links below: Books, Kindle e-Books, Music, etc.

These are obviously popular categories on Amazon, and Google tracks where users click, then uses that data to make serps more relevant.